# How to know actual result of `proc_output.waitFor` if `expected_output` is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, ros2

I am trying to follow a [ROS2 testing tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-1IhC01T1c) which tests a topic listener to understand how ROS2 testing works. Here is a screenshot of the related code at 21:15

[image]

I have a node `target_control_node` which subscribes the topic `turtle1/pose` and then move the turtle to a new random pose.

```
import math
import random

import rclpy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from rclpy.node import Node
from turtlesim.msg import Pose


class TargetControlNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("target_control_node")
        self.get_logger().info("target_control_node")
        self._target_pose = None
        self._cmd_vel_publisher = self.create_publisher(Twist, "turtle1/cmd_vel", 10)
        self.create_subscription(Pose, "turtle1/pose", self.subscribe_target_pose, 10)
        self.create_timer(1.0, self.control_loop)

    def subscribe_target_pose(self, msg):
        self._target_pose = msg

    def control_loop(self):
        if self._target_pose is None:
            return

        target_x = random.uniform(0.0, 10.0)
        target_y = random.uniform(0.0, 10.0)

        dist_x = target_x - self._target_pose.x
        dist_y = target_y - self._target_pose.y
        distance = math.sqrt(dist_x**2 + dist_y**2)

        msg = Twist()

        # position
        msg.linear.x = 1.0 * distance

        # orientation
        goal_theta = math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x)
        diff = goal_theta - self._target_pose.theta
        if diff > math.pi:
            diff -= 2 * math.pi
        elif diff < -math.pi:
            diff += 2 * math.pi
        msg.angular.z = 2 * diff

        self._cmd_vel_publisher.publish(msg)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = TargetControlNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am trying to write a simple test for the subscription part based on the tutorial above to understand how it works.

Here is my initial test code. Note inside I am using `expected_output=str(msg)`, however, it is wrong, and I am not sure what to put there.

```py
import pathlib
import random
import sys
import time
import unittest
import uuid

import launch
import launch_ros
import launch_testing
import pytest
import rclpy
import std_msgs.msg
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from turtlesim.msg import Pose


@pytest.mark.rostest
def generate_test_description():
    src_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent

    target_control_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        executable=sys.executable,
        arguments=[src_path.joinpath("turtle_robot/target_control_node.py").as_posix()],
        additional_env={"PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "1"},
    )

    return (
        launch.LaunchDescription(
            [
                target_control_node,
                launch_testing.actions.ReadyToTest(),
            ]
        ),
        {
            "target_control_node": target_control_node,
        },
    )


class TestTargetControlNodeLink(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        rclpy.init()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        rclpy.shutdown()

    def setUp(self):
        self.node = rclpy.create_node("target_control_test_node")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.node.destroy_node()

    def test_target_control_node(self, target_control_node, proc_output):
        pose_pub = self.node.create_publisher(Pose, "turtle1/pose", 10)

        try:
            msg = Pose()
            msg.x = random.uniform(0.0, 10.0)
            msg.y = random.uniform(0.0, 10.0)
            msg.theta = 0.0
            msg.linear_velocity = 0.0
            msg.angular_velocity = 0.0

            pose_pub.publish(msg)
            success = proc_output.waitFor(
                # `str(msg)` is wrong, however, I am not sure what to put here.
                expected_output=str(msg), process=target_control_node, timeout=1.0
            )
            assert success

        finally:
            self.node.destroy_publisher(pose_pub)
```

When I run `launch_test src/turtle_robot/test/test_target_control_node.py`, it only prints this without telling me what is actual output:

```bash
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/parallels/.ros/log/2023-01-02-16-37-27-631032-ubuntu-linux-22-04-desktop-1439830
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
test_target_control_node (test_target_control_node.TestTargetControlNodeLink) ... [INFO] [python3-1]: process started with pid [1439833]
[python3-1] [INFO] [1672706247.877402445] [target_control_node]: target_control_node
FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_target_control_node (test_target_control_node.TestTargetControlNodeLink)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my-ros/src/turtle_robot/test/test_target_control_node.py", line 91, in test_target_control_node
    assert success
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.061s

FAILED (failures=1)
[INFO] [python3-1]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[python3-1]
[python3-1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[python3-1]   File "/my-ros/src/turtle_robot/turtle_robot/target_control_node.py", line 59, in <module>
[python3-1]     main()
[python3-1]   File "/my-ros/src/turtle_robot/turtle_robot/target_control_node.py", line 53, in main
[python3-1]     rclpy.spin(node)
[python3-1]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 222, in spin
[python3-1]     executor.spin_once()
[python3-1]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 705, in spin_once
[python3-1]     handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(timeout_sec=timeout_sec)
[python3-1]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 691, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
[python3-1]     return next(self._cb_iter)
[python3-1]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 588, in _wait_for_ready_callbacks
[python3-1]     wait_set.wait(timeout_nsec)
[python3-1] KeyboardInterrupt
[ERROR] [python3-1]: process has died [pid 1439833, exit code -2, cmd '/usr/bin/python3 /my-ros/src/turtle_robot/turtle_robot/target_control_node.py --ros-args'].

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I checked the source code of [waitFor](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/b129eb65c9f03980c724b17200236290fa797816/launch_testing/launch_testing/io_handler.py#L148-L206), but still no clue.

Is there a way to print the actual output so that I can give correct `expected_output`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question(and give some more general tips): You can always print out the msg inside the node. That said, the reason you're getting an error is because `msg` is a *ros message type*, meaning it's an object. So by doing `str(msg)` your expected output will be something like `<object of type Pose at (some_address)>`; and not the actual message values. Also since it appears you're just testing a subscriber, it doesn't usually make sense to have a unit test that's expecting stdout. I would also note that you're publishing a message before actually waiting for the result, this should always fail. The reason is because by the time your subscriber is started, the message has already been published and is gone.

Finally, you shouldn't have a publisher included in any unit tests. It adds an extra dependency and since it's a prepackaged transport layer testing if it works is irrelevant. Instead to fix your problem you should simply be calling the individual methods of your node directly. Basically import the script, instantiate the object, and don't try to deal with the whole node lifecycle.

**Edit based on comments**

Looking at your subscriber code, you'll need to actually print something out. Unfortunately because it's not a std_msg(i.e. it has more fields than just `.data`) you'll need to decide how you want to go about confirming the data is right. You could simply look at one field or all of them in order. For example you might have in your test:

```
success = proc_output.waitFor(
            expected_output=str(msg.x), 
            process=target_control_node, timeout=1.0)
```

And in your control node:

```
def subscribe_target_pose(self, msg):
    self._target_pose = msg
    print(msg.x)
```

That said, this IO handling method doesn't seem like the best to me. Mainly because it relies on stdout which isn't something you always want.

Comment: Thanks @BTables! Those are very helpful suggestions! However, I am still wondering if I want to make it pass in this case, how can I arrange publish and subscribe, and what would be `expected_output` (if I can print the actual result, that would be helpful)

Comment: @HongboMiao sure, that's fair. Can you edit your question with the relevant section from your `target_control_node` subscriber? I can't give you an exact solution without seeing what it's trying to print out.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is only related with the fake `Pose` in the test. Just updated the question with the `target_control_node` codes!

Comment: @HongboMiao no worries. I've edited my answer to give the info you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm, still no luck. I feel the error should tell use what is actual value it gets..

Comment: @HongboMiao seems to me like you’re hitting a timeout then. Are you getting any additional output? You can also add a ros log statement next to the print to verify the callback is being called. It’s possible the namespaces aren’t right, which could be fixed by adding a leading `/` to your publisher/subscriber topic names. Overall this isn’t a great way to test and the tutorial author you linked really shouldn’t be telling people to do things this way.

Comment: Agree, unfortunately it lacks of documents and tutorials today for how to test ROS.   @BTables I created a reproducible [pull request](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/hongbomiao.com/pull/6600/files). And here is the [failure log](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/hongbomiao.com/actions/runs/3844534121/jobs/6547725375) which is exactly I got in local. Feel free to comment there, and post back to keep here clean. Really appreciate!